# Car not starting, headlights won't turn on

Tags: hyundai

I have a 2006 Hyundai Sonata V6.

The car is not starting,  there is no grinding when I turn the key, the battery sounds fairly strong, I believe the fuel pump is also humming in the back, however for some reason the headlights are not turning on at all when the car is off. Just the running lights on the sides, and the car still won't start.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: What test is "the battery sounds fairly strong" ?

Comment: But a battery charger on it for a few hours, if it now starts the battery may be failing or some light got left on overnight and drained the battery. If the battery is over 4 years old it is most suspect.

Comment: "however for some reason the headlights are not turning on at all when the car is off." That suggests to me the ignition switch isn't working. On a fairly modern car you shouldn't be able to switch the headlights on with the ignition off, so you can't accidentally leave the lights on and flatten the battery.

Comment: I just swapped for a new battery at AutoZone. Still not starting

Comment: I believe that I now know the issue. Fuel pump has gone out. I reach this conclusion for two reasons. One, because I cant hear it engaging at all and two, when I did spray starting fluid into the intake manifold it did start the car for 1-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Check the basics
First thing i do is spray in easy start
This will tell you if you have spark and fuel

Then use fastec method
Fuel
Air
Spark
Timing
Exhaust
Compression

It will be one of these-also check immobilser is not stopping injector/spark-try your spare key